# constant pointer arguments to function

Tags: c, function, constants

I have following piece of code where I am getting an error of

`error: expected expression before const (at line 15)`

```
 12 : int
 13 : function1(const char *arg1, const char **arg2)
 14 : {
 15 :        int i = function2(const char *arg1, const char **arg2);
 16 : }

 18 : int
 20 : function2(const char *arg1, const char **arg2)
 21 : {
 22 : }
```

what does that exactly mean?

Thanks

Comment: `int i = function2(arg1,arg2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `int i = function2(const char *arg1, const char **arg2);`
With  `int i = function2(arg1,arg2);`

Your variables are already defined.
when calling to function in C you shouldn't say parameters type , you have to pass parameters themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Line 15 is a mistake. In C, variables are identified by a single token called an *identifier*.

In this case, the names of the variables are `arg1` and `arg2`.  You use those tokens when you are using the variables; you don't repeat all of the type information associated with the variable.

So the line should be:

```
int i = function2(arg1, arg2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have `arg1` and `arg2` being passed in to your function1, so you just need

```
int i = function2(arg1, arg2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = function2(const char *arg1, const char **arg2);
```

You are trying to call function2, but you have written the call like a function declaration. You don't specify the argument types when calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the * and try? It seems like you're trying to pass arg1 and arg2 into function 2, but I don't think they can be referenced that way inside the function, because they weren't defined there. I believe it should be just 
`function2(arg1,arg2)`

Answer (score 1):

```
error: expected expression before const (at line 15)
```

**Q** What does that exactly mean?

**A** It means that the first thing after `function2(` is expected to be an expression. `const` is not an expression. `arg1` will be an expression.